# Ignore duplicate names to select required critera, excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am using the below formula to pull specific date based on 2 criteria's - date cell G1 & agent name cell G2:G12

the data has duplicates, so the same name may appear 4 times with different information next to each name. the formula will pick up the data from the first name that appears however I would like it to pick up a specific piece of data which could appear next to the 3rd duplicate.

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$11,MATCH($G$1&$G2,$A$1:$A$11&$B$1:$B$11,0))
```

Is there any way I can add to my current formula (or use another) where you ignore the names if they don't contain the specific required information?

Column C is the data, B shows possible duplicate names, E shows what data needs to be pulled from the data in C

[image]

Comment: I don't see, in your information, how you are deciding what *specific information* you want to return.

Comment: sorry - edited the question to try and make more sense and amended the screen shot

Comment: So if there are less than three duplicates, you want to return a blank?

Comment: So I want it to either return one of the exception codes from column E if they are next to a name, ignoring any others that aren't in the list (that may appear next to a duplicate name). If there are no exception codes from E appearing next to a name then return a blank.

Comment: Why not just use a filter?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing might be a filter.

But this **array** formula should work also.
I used Tables and Structured References, but you can change the references to cell references, if you don't want to.  But I find Tables very convenient to work with, as you automatically get dynamic range references.

```
H2:  =IFERROR(INDEX(Codes[Req Codes],AGGREGATE(14,6,MATCH(INDEX(fullTbl[[#All],[Exception code]],N(IF(1,1/((fullTbl[Date]=$G$1)*(fullTbl[Agent Name]=G2))*ROW(fullTbl)))),Codes,0),1)),"")
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

**EDIT**: for a formula not using tables/structured references, try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$5,AGGREGATE(14,6,MATCH(INDEX($C$1:$C$13,N(IF(1,1/(($A$2:$A$13=$G$1)*($B$2:$B$13=G2))*ROW($A$2:$C$13)))),$E$2:$E$5,0),1)),"")
```

[image]

### With the Advanced Filter:

[image]

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me, unless i'm doing something wrong. I've put the data in the same cells as above and used your formula with the array - =INDEX(E2:E5,AGGREGATE(14,6,MATCH(INDEX(A2:C13,C2:C13,N(IF(1,1/((A2:A13=$G$1)*(B2:B13=G2))*ROW(A2:C13)))),E2:E5,0),1))

Comment: @bprin87 You did not properly convert the references.  See my edit